# Upload csv file to Azure BLOB Storage

Tags: powershell, csv, azure

I'm trying to upload a file (csv file) to an azure blob storage.
I found a script (see below) but it keeps failing in the first try catch block.
As you run the script it asks you 2 things:

- localpath (mine is on my c-drive in a temp folder: c:\temp\test.csv)
- storagecontainer: I created a storage named "kepastorage" and within this I created a container "testfiles".

  ```
      [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $true)]
  param(
          [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
          [string]$LocalPath,

      # The name of the storage container to copy files to.
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
      [string]$StorageContainer,

      # If specified, will recurse the LocalPath specified.
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
      [switch]$RecurseLocalPath,

      # If specified, will create the storage container.
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
      [switch]$CreateStorageContainer,

      # If specified, will copy files to the container if the container already exists.
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
      [switch]$Force
  )

  # The script has been tested on Powershell 3.0
  Set-StrictMode -Version 3

  # Following modifies the Write-Verbose behavior to turn the messages on globally for this session
  $VerbosePreference = "Continue"

  # Check if Windows Azure Powershell is avaiable
  if ((Get-Module -ListAvailable Azure) -eq $null)
  {
      throw "Windows Azure Powershell not found! Please install from http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/#cmd-line-tools"
  }

  workflow UploadFilesInParallel
  {
      param(
          # The name of the storage container to copy files to.
          [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
          [string]$StorageContainer,

          # An array of files to copy to the storage container.
          [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
          [System.Object[]]$Files
      )

      if ($Files.Count -gt 0)
      {
          foreach -parallel ($file in $Files) 
          {
              $blobFileName = Split-Path -Path $file.FullName -NoQualifier
              try
              {
                  Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $StorageContainer `
                      -File $file.FullName -Blob $blobFileName `
                      -ConcurrentTaskCount 0 -Force
              }
              catch
              {
                  $warningMessage = "Unable to upload file " + $file.FullName
                  Write-Warning -Message $warningMessage
              }
          }
      }
  }

  # Ensure the local path given exists. Create it if switch specified to do so.
  if (-not (Test-Path $LocalPath -IsValid))
  {
      throw "Source path '$LocalPath' does not exist.  Specify an existing path."
  }

  # Get a list of files from the local folder.
  if ($RecurseLocalPath.IsPresent)
  {
      # $files = ls -Path $LocalPath -File -Recurse
      $files = @(ls -Path $LocalPath -File -Recurse)
  }
  else
  {
      # $files = ls -Path $LocalPath -File
      $files = @(ls -Path $LocalPath -File)
  }

  if ($files -ne $null -and $files.Count -gt 0)
  {
      # Create the storage container.
      if ($CreateStorageContainer.IsPresent)
      {
          $existingContainer = Get-AzureStorageContainer | 
              Where-Object { $_.Name -like $StorageContainer }

          if ($existingContainer)
          {
              $msg = "Storage container '" + $StorageContainer + "' already exists."
              if (!$Force.IsPresent -and !$PSCmdlet.ShouldContinue(
                      "Copy files to existing container?", $msg))
              {
                  throw "Specify a different storage container name."
              }
          }
          else
          {
              if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($StorageContainer, "Create Container"))
              {
                  $newContainer = New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $StorageContainer
                  "Storage container '" + $newContainer.Name + "' created."
              }
          }
      }

      # Upload the files to storage container.
      $fileCount = $files.Count
      if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($StorageContainer, "Copy $fileCount files"))
      {
          $time = [DateTime]::UtcNow
          UploadFilesInParallel -StorageContainer $StorageContainer -Files $files
          $duration = [DateTime]::UtcNow - $time

          "Uploaded " + $files.Count + " files to blob container '" + $StorageContainer + "'."
          "Total upload time: " + $duration.TotalMinutes + " minutes."
      }
  }
  else
  {
      Write-Warning "No files found."
  }
  ```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?
Thx.

Comment: The _only_ catch you have does not tell you what the actual error is. For debugging you could try adding `$_.Exception.Message` in you catch statement to let you focus better

Answer (score 1):

You could try this PowerShell script explained here: [Uploading a file to Azure Blob Storage](http://thecodegarden.net/uploading-to-azure-storage/).

```
$SubscriptionName = ""
$SubscriptionId = ""
$DestContainer = ""
$StorageAccountName = ""
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile -PublishSettingsFile "<Location of the publishsettings-file>"
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId -CurrentStorageAccountName $StorageAccountName
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File "<File you want to upload>" -Container $DestContainer
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've added the piece of script to my reply.